# bash echo multiple variables that overrides each other

Tags: string, bash, echo, prefix

I'm trying to print two variables in the same echo command in bash, the first variable "ID" is obtained by looking at the first line of a .c file. I strip the prefix to obtain ID = myid.

first line of .c file

```
// EID:myid
```

strip the prefix

```
firstLine=$(head -n 1 ~/my.c)
ID=${firstLine#*:}
```

if I echo $ID, I get "myid"; however, if I echo something along the line of:

```
randomString="random"
echo $ID$randomString
```

randomString will completely override my ID, and it'll only display

```
random
```

What am I missing about stripping prefix in bash? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .c file uses MS-DOS line endings and therefore `$ID` has a CR at the end. Strip that as well.